# Is $X\,X \rightarrow \overline{X} \,\overline{X} $ kind of baryon number violating reaction possible?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, cosmology, baryogenesis

I am reading Daniel Baumann's "Cosmology" book. In the part of Sakharov conditions,the third condition he mentions is the 'Departure from equilibrium'. To show the necessity of this condition, author gives an example reaction $$X\,X \rightarrow \overline{X}\ \overline{X} $$ where $X$ is a particle and $\overline{X}$ is its antiparticle. Usually we know particle and antiparticle can annihilate each other. But the above reaction says two particles becoming two antiparticles. Is such a reaction possible in the early universe?
[image: Screenshot of the paragraph from the book]